# Cannot open .jar file on MAC

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I have used this crawler many many many times.  At least once a day for the last few years.  All of the sudden today when I try to open the .jar file I get this: 'The Java JAR file “Crawler.jar” Check the Console for possible error messages.'  I have the latest version of java environment and SDK. I tried running 'java -jar Crawler.jar' and this was the result:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file     [data/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/log4j.properties (No such file or     directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:306)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:324)
at Crawler.main(Crawler.java:75)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [data/log4j.properties].
Failed to open connection.
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at DatabaseConnector.getConnection(DatabaseConnector.java:34)
at DatabaseConnector.foundTable(DatabaseConnector.java:65)
at TextOutput.<init>(TextOutput.java:21)
at Crawler.main(Crawler.java:77)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at DatabaseConnector.getConnection(DatabaseConnector.java:34)
at DatabaseConnector.foundTable(DatabaseConnector.java:65)
at TextOutput.<init>(TextOutput.java:21)
at Crawler.main(Crawler.java:77)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at DatabaseConnector.foundTable(DatabaseConnector.java:68)
at TextOutput.<init>(TextOutput.java:21)
at Crawler.main(Crawler.java:77)
```

I am not a Java guy at all.  If anyone has any insight on what I can do to fix this it would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Care! Your harddrive could missfunction. Basically if nothing is changed your jar file got corrupted -> you need to get it again from somewhere.

Comment: It looks like a mySql base conenction refused and, maybe, log4j.properties file corrupted as well. It's (database) unlikely contained in a jar (but possible). Somebody set it up somewhere somehow at some time. Get a new version of this jar, maybe it was broken (hardware failure killed some configuration files or something else). If it isn't helping, - .jar or better a sources needed for finding your database and logger configurations.

Comment: Some mysql db is refusing the connection (as stated by the message, and some property is not found, but seems not to be a fatal issue)

Comment: It's trying to connect to a database somewhere and failing.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  I have never come across this issue before which is so strange.  The only thing I can think of is that I had a software update for my iMac since the last time I ran the crawler.  I am not sure if that possibly had anything to do with it.